# How to combine the current year with the next Model Id and save it in a field

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I am using Django 1.8.6 with Python 2.7.8. I am trying to save a Model called Project with the field "jobNumber", which is a combination of the current year plus a 4 character string of the Model's next Id. Example: The year is 2016, the next Id of the model will be 1, make that a 4 char string and it is 0001, add the year and char together the field value should be "20160001".

Here is my Model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    jobNumber = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    contractor = models.ForeignKey(Contractor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=101)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Project_created_by')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Project_modified_by')
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.modified_date = timezone.now()
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the next id until you save, because it is allocated by the database on insert. So there is really no alternative but to save twice.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        year = datetime.datetime.now().year
        self.jobNumber = '{}{:04d}'.format(year, self.id)
    super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that you should be using `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` for `created_date` and `modified_date` respectively, which would remove the need to set them yourself in the save method.